# How is backdoor criterion used in practice?

Tags: causality, bayesian-network, dag, causal-diagram

Is the backdoor criterion applicable only for "learning" in a causal model (i.e. for estimating the causal effects between variables) or must it also be used when running that model, as in calculating posterior probabilities when trying to estimate the impact of an intervention?

Comment: It is usually considered only from a conceptual standpoint, i.e. the investigators are planning their study and data collection and power, and they draw a bunch of possible causal factors between the exposure and outcome of interest.

Comment: @AdamO you mean it is basically used like a rule-of-thumb? That's no surprise as I have read so many views on the topic but no real-world application or even critique.

Comment: That's not how I see it. Most people falsely assume statisticians get started once they have the data in front of them. But in practice and in theory that's not case: you need to formulate hypotheses, and propose statistical models, and provide rationale for estimands as answers to scientific questions of interest. This all must take place before you even start collecting data, or else is at risk of being compromised or biased. Causal modeling is a framework for doing much of that.

Comment: @AdamO I agree with every word, it's just that I don't see any reference to the backdoor criterion in there. I can only see this as some sort of philosophical grounding for the scientific method (perhaps the rule-of-thumb term came out as too dismissive).

Comment: I sense I'm close to offering all this as answer, except that you might have your own notions and you might be asking this question ironically. As I already said, before collecting data, you would write down a "conceptual model", and classify variables as confounders, and you choose a subset of those confounders for adjustment based on meeting the backdoor criterion. I supported R and K awards that received funding, all of which justified the model at precisely that level of detail. In other words, it's anything but a thought experiment.

Comment: My only notion is that I have only seen the criterion mentioned in textbooks without any practical examples of use. Perhaps I've had a wrong scope in my literature review and haven't come across any model justifications in the way you describe.

Comment: Not true. There's an example in every text I can think of. Look at Hernan, Robins "Causal Inference" right on the same paragraph of the definition on page 88 is a worked example on determinants of Ovarian Cancer https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2021/03/ciwhatif_hernanrobins_30mar21.pdf.